# Python Twisted sendLine()

Tags: python, twisted

No not you again.

Well anyway I've been struggling with this for quite some time. So basically I have my twisted application and now I'm writing a PyQt interface for it. There's only one thing I haven't been able to bridge between the Twisted script and the new interface yet. That's when a button is being pressed get Twisted to send some data via the sendLine() function.

We can't use.

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_7, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),
           Twisted().Button_Clicked('abc'))


class Twisted(LineReceiver):

   def Button_Clicked(self,out):
        self.sendLine(out)
```

This results in:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 296, in sendLine
    return self.transport.write(line + self.delimiter)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Can anyone give an example of how we could send some data when a PyQt button has been pressed?

Thanks Bye!

Comment: What do you mean by "No not you again."?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just instantiate `Twisted()` and then use it; it's a `Protocol`, and `Protocol`s must be instantiated via a `Factory`, in response to either connecting a client or accepting an incoming connection as a server.  The error that you're seeing is telling you that `Twisted`'s transport doesn't exist at the point where the button is clicked, so there's nowhere to send the data.

Since I'm assuming you're writing a client, you probably want to read the [Writing Clients](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/core/howto/clients.html) tutorial.

Comment: Well this leaves me with a bit of a dilemma. How can I initiate a protocol via factory when the user pushes a button. The only way I can currently think of is when the first person connects start off a deferred via connectionMade(): and have it constaly send data. Each time checking if what it's currently trying to send is the same as what it sent last time and if so then don't. This is rather scruffy though. Is there another way?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  You just need to call `connectTCP`, or something like it, to make the connection.  Then later, write some data to it.  You don't need to keep sending anything, just have a check in your `Button_Clicked` method which checks to see if a connection is either up (in which case you need to send data to it), being made (in which case you need to append your data to a buffer which will be sent when it is connected) or not made yet (in which case you need to kick it off).